# javascript variable to call object function

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I'm new to OOP, so please excuse me if my terminology is off. I'm trying to use a function parameter to call an object argument.

I think this would be more understandable with sample code:

#### JS

```
$(".color").click(function()
{
    var newColor = $(this).attr("data-color");
    functions.colors.show(newColor);
});

var functions =
{
    colors:
    {
        show: function(newColor)
        {
            $("h1").text(myTexts.test.newColor);
        }
    }
} // end functions

var myTexts =
{
    test:
    {
        red: "Bright red",
        green: "Grassy green",
        blue: "Sky blue"
    }
} // end texts
```

As you can see, I'm trying to get, say, "Sky blue", to show up inside my h1. However, when I click, say, to show "Bright red", this is not working.

As reference, here is my HTML:

#### HTML

```
<span class="color" data-color="red">Red</span>
<span class="color" data-color="green">Green</span>
<span class="color" data-color="blue">Blue</span>
```

From my understanding, when I click a color, I my color (data-color attribute) is parsed into the "show()" function, but I can't get the proper text to show up.

Why is that ?

Comment: Just a side note: this code has nothing to do with object oriented programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [`bracket notation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) at this context,

```
$("h1").text(myTexts.test[newColor]);
```

Full code,

```
var functions =
{
    colors:
    {
        show: function(newColor)
        {
            $("h1").text(myTexts.test[newColor]);
        }
    }
}
```

---

And as well as you should use [`.data(key)`](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-key) while fetching a data attribute..

```
var newColor = $(this).data("color");
```

Comment: Oh, so I wasn't *that* far off. Will mark as accepted as soon as allowed, thanks for the rapid feedback!